# If I convert, must I have a beard?

Tags: clothing, beard

Basically what I said. If I convert and become a Muslim, am I required to grow/maintain a beard?

Comment: I think you want to start your life as a Muslim more likely based and concerned on symbols instead of beliefs. I mean a beard doesn't make a Muslim, as anybody else could let a beard grow, what makes a Muslim is his belief and the acts his doing according to the teaching of Quran and Sunnah. So starting with your heart and soul seems to me more important. Maybe this post has some relevance http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/is-it-compulsory-for-imam-of-a-masjid-mosque-to-have-a-beard

Answer (score 3):

While it is NOT a part of the core principles of Islam that you must maintain beard to be or stay Muslim, it is highly recommended part of the attire of a Muslim male.

To **some school of jurisdiction**, (e.g. Hanafi), it is obligatory, but not part of the basic believes as I mentioned earlier. Hence, dropping it intentionally is considered a sin. But, still Muslim.

The above short explanation is applicable in general, however please also keep in mind that **Islam also don't burden someone beyond his/her abilities or context**.

ALLAH knows the best. I just tried to give an idea of the concept.

Comment: So, intentionally not growing a beard is a sin, but if you can't grow one, it's okay?

Comment: Yes, it's okay. I think that's the general idea of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. You would still be considered as a Muslim. Growing beards is highly encouraged in Islam and considered as a Sunnah. But not growing one won't make you a non-Muslim.

Answer (score 1):

> If I convert, must I have a beard?

Of note, albeit having beard from Islamic view of point --at least based on Shia Islam-- is regarded as a necessary/wajib (mandatory) act, but it doesn't mean that if you shave your beard (and if you don't keep your beard in its at least Islamic size) you are not a Muslim anymore!

Hence, despite shaving your beard, you'll be still a Muslim --if you have converted to Islam or you have born as a Muslim-- but pay heed that it can be regarded as a kind of sin or disobeying if you don't obey his order or ...

Answer (score 0):

Growing beard is a Sunnah. You will be rewarded if you do it, but it is not a sin if you don't do it.

Comment: Well some schools of thought and majority consider it as an important Sunnah so if you leave such Sunnah as Sunnah Mukkadah one time or few  it wont be considered as a sin but if it is continuous then it would be a sin.

Comment: بشروا و لا تنفروا ، يقول الرجل أن ليس بمسلم أساسا و يريد أن يدخل الإسلام و انت تحدثه عن السنن و انواعها ؟ دعه يعتق رقبته من النار أولا و يواظب على الفروض ثم حدثه عن السنن عندما يتمكن الدين من قلبه. هدانا و هداك الله لما يحب و يرضى .

Comment: Yeah I agree to your point but the thing is he asked himself about sharai ruling for important Sunnah so the answer should be rightly explained with wisdom.JazakAllah.Arabic not my first language but could understand to some extent.